# CSS li containing class but not class disabled

Tags: css

Im trying to get my hover selecting work properly.

Im having two classes in a li element.
It may have the class named `disabled` , or it may have a class called `wait` , or it may have both `disabled` and `wait`

I want this hover to only work on the li element with the class named `wait`, but only if `disabled` class is not on it.

How can i achieve this?

Current attempt:

```
.group li:.wait:not(.disabled):hover {
// do something

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a `:` after your `li`, which signified that the following element in your query would be a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). However, you just wanted a simple class selector: `.wait`.

```css
.group li.wait:not(.disabled):hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="group">
  <li>None</li>
  <li class="wait">Wait</li>
  <li class="disabled">Disabled</li>
  <li class="wait disabled">Wait and Disabled</li>
</ul>
```